# jcrop is not working properly with IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jcrop

I have used crop in my .net web application. All the browsers are pretty much fine with the code. However, IE shows weird behaviour. I have tried other posts but they are either not helpful or kind of a hack. here is the javascript code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
                api = $('<%= "#" + target.ClientID %>').Jcrop({
                    onChange: showCoords,
                    onSelect: showCoords,
                    onRelease: clearCoords,
                    aspectRatio: 1
                }, function () {
                    api = this;
                    api.setSelect([10, 10, 110, 110]);
                    api.setOptions({ bgFade: true });
                    api.ui.selection.addClass('jcrop-selection');
                });

            });
```

on first try IE fails to load the dotted lines but sometimes on second try it works. Seems kind of timing issue or image loading problem...Thanks

Comment: Sorry for not updating my post. Actually I found the problem, so I will first mention what is wrong with IE, then will describe my solution. As I stated in the question is a timing issue. IE loads the script before getting the picture from server. To resolve that you have to wait until the picture is downloaded:     $('<%= "#" + target.ClientID %>').load(function () {api = $('<%= "#" + target.ClientID %>').Jcrop({... and the target is obviously my asp:Image control. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks beebee. The symptoms seemed the same, but mine was due to the target having no display (my Jcrop interface is hidden until an image is loaded). Changing it to `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`(along with some positioning) fixed it.

Comment: @beebee You should put your comment as the answer. I found it also solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually I found the problem, so I will first mention what is wrong with IE, then will describe my solution. As I stated in the question is a timing issue. IE loads the script before getting the picture from server.
>
> To resolve that you have to wait until the picture is downloaded:
>
> ```
> $('<%= "#" + target.ClientID %>').load(function () {
>     api = $('<%= "#" + target.ClientID %>').Jcrop({...
> ```
>
> and the target is obviously my `asp:Image` control.

Comment: This is not the documented way to use jcrop, please read the documentation.

Comment: @Brunis Please clarify. jCrop has [ie specific bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjcrop%5D%5Bie%5D+is%3Aanswer) which are not part of its documentation.